# bandwith charge between ec2 and RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I'm using aws to run php app and it works good.
But I have a question: Does Any one knows if accessing to RDS from ec2 in the same region can trigger bandwith charge ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both the RDS and EC2 servers are in the same availability zone then there is no data transfer charge. If they are in different availability zones then there is the standard data transfer charge on the EC2 instance, but no transfer charge on the RDS instance. In addition, there is no charge for RDS data replication between availability zones.

This information used to be on [this page](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/), but now I can't find it. You can see some of this information in the [RDS FAQ page](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/). There is also a discussion thread on the official RDS forum [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=47162).

Comment: Thanks for help @mabaird It's really weird this last 12hours I created a cronjob runs every 3 sec read from rds then on billing details I got 100mb of bandwidth (regional transfer) the aws support doesn't have an answer for my question

Comment: Are you sure your RDS server and EC2 server are in the same availability zone?

Comment: Yes in the same region

Comment: Region and availability zone are 2 different things. They would have to be in the same availability zone to prevent any bandwidth charges.